# Failure deploying Simplest portlet in jetspeed

Tags: tomcat, portlet, jetspeed2

I am referring to following webpage to build my portlet on Jetspeed 2.
Everything is fine, but after deployment, It says-
Failed to retrieve Portlet Definition for simplest::Simplest

Following is the jetspeed-deployment.log contents-
03.11.2011 18:21:51 ERROR [org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.fireDeploymentEvent():240] Failure deploying E:\Jetspeed-2.2.2\webapps\jetspeed\WEB-INF\deploy\simplest.war
04.11.2011 09:41:33 ERROR [org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.dispatch():273] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WEB-INF/portlet.xml
org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WEB-INF/portlet.xml
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.DeployPortletAppEventListener.deployPortletApplication(DeployPortletAppEventListener.java:224)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.DeployPortletAppEventListener.invokeDeploy(DeployPortletAppEventListener.java:207)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.dispatch(StandardDeploymentManager.java:264)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.deploy(StandardDeploymentManager.java:178)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.fireDeploymentEvent(StandardDeploymentManager.java:209)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager$FileSystemScanner.run(StandardDeploymentManager.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WEB-INF/portlet.xml
    at org.apache.jetspeed.tools.deploy.JetspeedDeploy.(JetspeedDeploy.java:182)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.tools.deploy.JetspeedDeploy.(JetspeedDeploy.java:96)
    at org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.DeployPortletAppEventListener.deployPortletApplication(DeployPortletAppEventListener.java:219)
    ... 5 more

Please any reply will be helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

After I saw the exception as follows, I saw the file of `org.apache.jetspeed.deployment.impl.StandardDeploymentManager.java`, at head you will see a method of `start()`, you can debug this method to find the details. If there is no exception in it, the best way is to check whether the `simplest.war` project is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the configuration in the psml file related to your application has correct portlet name?

```
- First create new psml, change in it page id name, change title, short title, fragment id of portlet, its name
- In the deployed project, in web.xml change the name to be similar to the folder name in web apps folder
```

Also in portlet xml file change the portlet name to be similar to the one written in the psml file